# What to use to compile and simulate Verilog programs on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, verilog, hdl

I am required to simulate Verilog programs as part of my syllabus. But, my college uses Xilinx ISE, and it isn't available for Mac.

So please help me out with the best software and also some detailed steps on how to install and use them.

Answer (score 8):

You could try [Icarus Verilog](http://iverilog.icarus.com/), which is a free Verilog simulator.

According to the instructions [here](http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Installation_Guide) you can install Icarus Verilog on Mac OS X.

Comment: The first link requires a google log in.

Answer (score 3):

You call also use `brew install icarus-verilog` it will directly install it in MacOS without building the binaries for them individually.