# Is there any Verilog IDE for Mac

Tags: macos, ide, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

As indicated in the heading, I'm looking for an IDE for **Verilog**. I am a *Mac* user, but I couldn't find any (good) one, especially one that has more or less  the same functionality as Eclipse.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried Icarus Verilog (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369725/what-to-use-to-compile-and-simulate-verilog-programs-on-mac-os-x-10-6-8)?

Comment: @Bucco Icarus Verilog is a simulator and synthesis tool; I dont believe it has an IDE. You could always adapt eclipse for Verilog (which probably has been done but  Im not sure if something exists for easy download)

Comment: @Bucco I know Icarus actually, but I'm looking for more practical and useful editor/compiler-like tool for Verilog.

Comment: verilog-mode for emacs is by far the most powerful environment for Verilog: http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [SVEditor](http://sveditor.sourceforge.net/) a try! It's an Eclipse-based IDE with some basic [features](http://sveditor.sourceforge.net/SVEditor_Features.html).